# Flexbox Form not covering entire site

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox, css-grid

It happens that my "form" has 3 divs "(.contact-in)" which i call them with ":nth-child" in my css and with flex i do control their percentage on the site but in x-axis. So my question is how can i control their % in y-axis because they aren't covering the entire site and for example my footer isn't going all the way down because i'm not covering the entire page with the content.

Postscript: The site layout is with css grid.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/contact.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;700;900&family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>TRV ECOLOGICO SRL</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <nav class="contenedor-nav">
            <div class="menu-navegacion">
                <div class="logo">
                <div class="contenedor-triangulo">                    
                    <div class="triangulo"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="contenedor-texto">
                    <div class="textotriangulo"><h2>TRV ECOLOGICO SRL</h2></div>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="menu-lista">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=index.html>INICIO</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>PRODUCTOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>EMPRESA</a></li>
                    <li><a href=contact.html>CONTACTO</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="contenedor-form">
            <div class="contact-wrap">
                <div class="contact-in">
                    <h1>Información de Contacto</h1>
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>Teléfono</h2>
                    <p>123 - 4567 - 8901</p>
                    <p>011 - 1234 - 5678</p>
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>Email</h2>
                    <p>asd@asdfgh.com.ar</p>
                    <p>asd@asdfgh.com.ar</p>
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>Dirección</h2>
                    <p>Morón, Buenos Aires, Argentina</p>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-in">
                    <h1>Contacto</h1>
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre Completo" class="contact-in-input">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre Completo" class="contact-in-input">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre Completo" class="contact-in-input">
                        <textarea placeholder="Mensaje" class="contact-in-textarea"></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="contact-in-btn">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-in">
                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d52502.855079198634!2d-58.65170330080583!3d-34.6691347508206!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x95bcc76f57e3be01%3A0xa488fcdcec5b600f!2sMor%C3%B3n%2C%20Provincia%20de%20Buenos%20Aires!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sar!4v1618120836940!5m2!1ses!2sar" width="100%" height="auto" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="contenedor-footer">
            <div id="footer">
                <p>TRV ECOLOGICO SRL - Todos los derechos reservados</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;  
}
body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
}
/*GRID CONTENEDOR*/
.contenedor{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
}
.contenedor .contenedor-nav{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 4;
}
.contenedor .contenedor-form{
    grid-column: span 2;
}
.contenedor .contenedor-footer{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 4;
}
/* MENU NAVEGACION*/
nav{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 30;
}
.menu-navegacion{    
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;    
    height: 80px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
}
.logo{
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 20%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 1%;
    position: relative;
}
.contenedor-triangulo{
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.triangulo{
    height: 0%;
    width: 0%;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid red;
    display: block;
}
.contenedor-texto{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
.textotriangulo{
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 1em;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 1px rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.493);
}
.menu-lista{
    margin-right: 20%;
}
.menu-lista ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;    
}
.menu-lista ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 20px;        
}
/* FORM */
.contact-wrap{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.contact-in{
    padding: 40px 30px;
}
.contact-in:nth-child(1){
    flex: 30%;
    background: url(../images-form/1.jpg);
    color: #fff;
}
.contact-in:nth-child(2){
    flex: 45%;
    background: #c31432;
}
.contact-in:nth-child(3){
    flex: 25%;
    padding: 0;
}
.contact-in h1{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.contact-in h2{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.contact-in h2 i{
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 50px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.contact-in p{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.contact-in form{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.contact-in-input{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.contact-in-textarea{
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.contact-in-btn{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.contact-in iframe{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}
@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
    .contact-in:nth-child(1){
        flex: 50%;        
    }
    .contact-in:nth-child(2){
        flex: 50%;        
    }
    .contact-in:nth-child(3){
        flex: 100%;        
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:360px){
    .contact-in:nth-child(1){
        flex: 50%;        
    }
    .contact-in:nth-child(2){
        flex: 50%;        
    }
    .contact-in:nth-child(3){
        flex: 100%;        
    }
}
/* FOOTER */
#footer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);    
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}
#footer p{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: solid white 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make the `height` of `html` and `body` to `100%`.

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
```

If you want to make the footer height is to be `80px`, then make it in `contenedor`  class

```
.contenedor{
    ...
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto) 80px;
}
```

Why to make height internally `80px` when you can control it with `grid` using `grid-template-rows`.

```
#footer{
    ...
    height: 80px; // Should be avoided as per your design
    ...           // instead add height for whole footer in grid-tempate-rows
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
}


/*GRID CONTENEDOR*/

.contenedor {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto) 80px;
}

.contenedor .contenedor-nav {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}

.contenedor .contenedor-form {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.contenedor .contenedor-footer {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
}


/* MENU NAVEGACION*/

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 30;
}

.menu-navegacion {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
}

.logo {
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 1%;
  position: relative;
}

.contenedor-triangulo {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.triangulo {
  height: 0%;
  width: 0%;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid red;
  display: block;
}

.contenedor-texto {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.textotriangulo {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 1em;
  text-shadow: 3px 2px 1px rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.493);
}

.menu-lista {
  margin-right: 20%;
}

.menu-lista ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-lista ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
}


/* FORM */

.contact-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contact-in {
  padding: 40px 30px;
}

.contact-in:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 30%;
  background: url(../images-form/1.jpg);
  color: #fff;
}

.contact-in:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 45%;
  background: #c31432;
}

.contact-in:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 25%;
  padding: 0;
}

.contact-in h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.contact-in h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.contact-in h2 i {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-in p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contact-in form {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.contact-in-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.contact-in-textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.contact-in-btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.contact-in iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .contact-in:nth-child(1) {
    flex: 50%;
  }
  .contact-in:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 50%;
  }
  .contact-in:nth-child(3) {
    flex: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:360px) {
  .contact-in:nth-child(1) {
    flex: 50%;
  }
  .contact-in:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 50%;
  }
  .contact-in:nth-child(3) {
    flex: 100%;
  }
}


/* FOOTER */

#footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

#footer p {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: solid white 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <nav class="contenedor-nav">
    <div class="menu-navegacion">
      <div class="logo">
        <div class="contenedor-triangulo">
          <div class="triangulo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="contenedor-texto">
          <div class="textotriangulo">
            <h2>TRV ECOLOGICO SRL</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-lista">
        <ul>
          <li><a href=index.html>INICIO</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>PRODUCTOS</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>EMPRESA</a></li>
          <li><a href=contact.html>CONTACTO</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="contenedor-form">
    <div class="contact-wrap">
      <div class="contact-in">
        <h1>Información de Contacto</h1>
        <h2><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>Teléfono</h2>
        <p>123 - 4567 - 8901</p>
        <p>011 - 1234 - 5678</p>
        <h2><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>Email</h2>
        <p>asd@asdfgh.com.ar</p>
        <p>asd@asdfgh.com.ar</p>
        <h2><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>Dirección</h2>
        <p>Morón, Buenos Aires, Argentina</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-in">
        <h1>Contacto</h1>
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre Completo" class="contact-in-input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre Completo" class="contact-in-input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre Completo" class="contact-in-input">
          <textarea placeholder="Mensaje" class="contact-in-textarea"></textarea>
          <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="contact-in-btn">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-in">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d52502.855079198634!2d-58.65170330080583!3d-34.6691347508206!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x95bcc76f57e3be01%3A0xa488fcdcec5b600f!2sMor%C3%B3n%2C%20Provincia%20de%20Buenos%20Aires!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sar!4v1618120836940!5m2!1ses!2sar"
          width="100%" height="auto" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="contenedor-footer">
    <div id="footer">
      <p>TRV ECOLOGICO SRL - Todos los derechos reservados</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Making the height of html and body to 100% isn't working. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: not just height, I've added more code and explanation